# Hardware: Connecting multiple wires to one pin

Tags: pi-3, hardware

I'm using the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.

Currently I have a RTC and an Accelerometer attached to my Raspberry Pi. They take up the following pins:

RTC:

1, 3, 5 and 9

Accelerometer:

4, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 32 and 36

Now I want to add one more external unit. The unit is the Xbee S1. This unit needs the following pins:

(pin number in the parenthesis)

3.3 V (1 or 17), GND (6, 9, 14, 20, 25, 30, 34 or 39), TX (8) and RX (10)

The RTC and Accelerometer already take up pin 1 and 17. So I need to figure out how to get acces to a 3.3 V pin. I was thinking the following:

- Is it possible to connect two wires from two different external units to the same 3.3 V pin?

Comment: What Accelerometer are you using? Is that mounted on a module?

Comment: I use the ADXL345 accelerometer

Answer (score 1):

You can connect multiple wires to the power rail pins.

The power rail pins are the 5V pins, the 3V3 pins, and the ground pins.